# Adding multiple functions to an external javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on adding javascript functionality to a basic HTML page with multiple buttons.  The code works when I include one function in my external JS file, but stops working when I try to add another piece of button functionality.

How do I fix this issue?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jiggle Into JavaScript</title>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>

    <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

    <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

    <button id="button1">Grow</button>
    <button id="button2">Blue</button>
    <button id="button3">Fade</button>
    <button id="button4">Reset</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Snippet:

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("box").style.height = "500px";
});

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("box").style.background-color = "blue";
});
```

```html
<p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>
<div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>
<button id="button1">Grow</button>
<button id="button2">Blue</button>
<button id="button3">Fade</button>
<button id="button4">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Did you bother opening the Javascript console? It would have told you where the error was.

Answer (score 6):

You have incorrect syntax here:

```
document.getElementById("box").style.background-color = "blue";
```

`-` is the subtraction operator, it can't be used as part of a property literal. Style properties are created by converting the CSS name to camelCase, so it should be:

```
document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also used simple `background`

```
document.getElementById("box").style.background = "blue";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged `JQuery` too, here is the JQuery version. In JQuery, you can use `css()` where you can add/change multiple CSS properties:

```js
$("#button1").on('click', function() {
  $("#box").css({
    'height': '500px'
  });
})

$("#button2").on('click', function() {
  $("#box").css({
    'background-color': 'blue'
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Jiggle Into JavaScript</title>
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
</head>

<body>

  <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

  <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

  <button id="button1">Grow</button>
  <button id="button2">Blue</button>
  <button id="button3">Fade</button>
  <button id="button4">Reset</button>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you wanted a JQuery answer here is one too.

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var $box = $('#box');
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'button1')
    {
        $box.css('height','500px');
    }
    else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'button2')
    {
        $box.css('background-color', 'blue');
    }
});
```